# My SQL: Add if condition in where statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I want to select all customers or one customer from same SP. Right now we are mantaining two SPs to get these details:

i.e. To get all customers:

```
select id, name from customers
```

and to get one customer:

```
select id, name from customers
where id=id_from_input
```

To make them common, i thought of pasing `id_from_input` as null to get all customers. I tried several ways to make a conditional where statement in my sql that would work with this plan, but nothing is working. For example:

```
select id, name from customers
where if(id_from_input <> null) id=id_from_input; end if
```

gives me syntax error.

How can I make a `where` clause that returns all rows when `id_from_input` is null, the matching row otherwise?

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is the `IF` syntax for Queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `x <> null` is never true; you can only use `is null`, or `is not null`, to test for null. Correcting your attempt gives:

```
select id, name from customers
where id_from_input is null or id = id_from_input
```

Or for something more terse (and IMHO elegant):

```
select id, name from customers
where id = coalesce(id_from_input, id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE Statement to achieve your result :

```
SELECT id, name FROM customers WHERE id = CASE WHEN ISNULL(id_from_input,'') 
<> '' THEN id_from_input ELSE id END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `or`:

```
select id, name
from customers
where id_from_input is null or id = id_from_input
```

if `id_from_input` is null then `or` clause will not be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

`select id, name from customers where
  CASE     WHEN id_from_input<>null THEN  id=id_from_input
   ELSE  id  END`